# Option Set from CDS with Trigger Condition

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to put a trigger condition in **"When a record is created, updated or deleted"**.

I tried all the trigger conditions I saw in this forum, but unfortunately, it's not working.

It is an **Option Set** in the CDS entity.

This is my trigger condition:

> ```
> @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/statuscode'], 'Billed')
> ```

I also tried this one:

> ```
> @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/statuscode']?['Value'], 'Billed')
> ```

Here's the screenshot.

[image: Trigger Condition Screenshot]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the integer property, not the label value, because the value passed from Dataverse for the `statuscode` field is going to be an integer value.

You can find the integer value by looking at the field in the Power Apps Maker portal.